# How to check if field exists that has isRequired set to true in WCF

Tags: wcf, datamember

I have a DataMember(isRequired:=True) that property is called FillerInd. Now how do you tell if that field is empty or does not exist? I was reading online and you have to do some Serialization and Deserialization of XML if it has the field required missing it will throw the exception MissingMethodException. I have no idea of how to implement this or if this is the best route to take. Any help to put me into correct path I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The DataMember property `IsRequired` tells you whether the property is required *on the wire*: whether it should be present in the message or not. A typical situation where this would cause exceptions is when the service updates the DataContract by adding a property with `IsRequired = true`, without notifying the clients. The clients will send serialized objects that don't include the property, causing an exception to be thrown.

A less typical situation but easy way to reproduce this problem using a property of a basic type is to explicitly set the [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) property to false. If you do this, and then try to call an operation with an object of that DataContract, an exception may be thrown. Consider this example:

```
// Data Contract
[DataContract]
public class Animal
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name;
}

// IService
[OperationContract]
int GetIdentifier(Animal animal);

// Client operation
int id = client.GetIdentifier(new Animal()); // Causes exception
```

This will cause a [SerializationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationexception.aspx) (in turn causing a CommunicationException) with a message along these lines:

> Member Name in type ....Animal cannot be serialized. This exception is usually caused by trying to use a null value where a null value is not allowed. The 'Name' member is set to its default value (usually null or zero). The member's EmitDefault setting is 'false', indicating that the member should not be serialized. However, the member's IsRequired setting is 'true', indicating that it must be serialized. This conflict cannot be resolved.  Consider setting 'Name' to a non-default value. Alternatively, you can change the EmitDefaultValue property on the DataMemberAttribute attribute to true, or changing the IsRequired property to false.

Note that if you bypass this issue client side (e.g. by editing the reference.cs for a generated service reference so that the DataMember is not required anymore on the client side), then the service will encounter an exception when deserializing, which will cause a Fault, I believe.

---

Turning to your specific remarks and questions.

You don't have to do anything to tell if the field is empty: the WCF framework handles this for you. If needed I suppose you could hook into the (de)serialization to get the heads up on this issue, or even inspect the message before it's handled.

As I said, this situation will cause SerializationExceptions and CommunicationExceptions, not a [MissingMethodException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception.aspx).

Whether you need "IsRequired" and whether it's the "best route to take" I wouldn't know. This depends on your situation, of course.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly and one uses a class as a parameter to a method and a client will call that method, it will throw an exception upon sending? Or do I understand the `EmitDefaultValue` wrong?

Comment: Yes, afaik that's what happens. To clafiry: a *WCF* client will throw an exception if you try to send (and thus serialize) an object where a required property isn't set and EmitDefaultValue is false. If you'd have a client that bypasses this, then the *service* will throw an exception upon de-serializing.

Comment: I've just tested it, but it is not entirely true (no offense). It will throw an exception if it's set to the default value. If I mark a boolean with `Required=true, EmitDefaultValue=false` and I set that boolean explicitly on the client side to `false` it will still throw an exception. It is logical of course. There would be no way for the service to know if the property is really set without a tripple state. For value types I can stick to `Nullable<T>` in that case and for strings and classes I could make a difference between `String.Empty` and `null`. Thanks tough, this is really helpfull.

Comment: @Silvermind None taken. You're correct of course! Feel free to edit my answer to reflect that extra bit of info!

Comment: Thanks guys for helping out with the question. Now I have a WCF Web Service that is referencing another project witch contains Models. Now if I specify isRequired on a properties of a model and if the client does not send that property the error does not occur. Am I doing something wrong? Also does the error occur only on a NULL object or does it also occur if it is String.Empty or ""? I am trying to identify the best route to take to validate the fields.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. I suggest you [inspect the message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) and if you're still having trouble understanding why it's not working for your specific situation open up a follow-up question where you post your code.